# Implementation of Azure Machine Learning

Tags: azure, machine-learning

Last day, I was asked to go through Azure ML for a project which basically sells electronics goods. By going through the guides, it just says we can predict a user's requirement based on history.

How do we implement ML in such a website selling electronic goods. Say for example, I wish to show predictions for 'similar products' and 'those who bough this product also bought'. How do we do this ?

Comment: that's too broad Q for stack overflow, I suggest that you take it to technet

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use the Azure ML matchobox recommender, there is a very nice movie recommender built with Azure ML...
However if you want to get down that line you will have to go much further than the movie recommender sample .
You start here any way: 
https://gallery.cortanaanalytics.com/Experiment/Recommender-Movie-recommendation-3